# Return multiple values ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This is my first time working with AJAX, I am creating a drum loop generator, instead of having to refresh the page to create a new loop I would like to try AJAX.

When #button1 is clicked it runs generate.php,  I am trying to return multiple values from the generate.php echo and place them in different elements on the page.

The different values are the file url to be placed in audio src, background image url, the number of bars the loop is, and the BPM of the loop. They are separated by commas in the php echo.

I get an error in google developer tools that says "jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4 GET https://whatever.com/random/undefined 404 (Not Found)" when I click the button

**Button:**

```
<div id="button1"><div class="namething">Generate</div></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
$('#button1').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'generate.php',
        data: $(this).val(),                 
        success: function(value){
             var data = value.split(",");
            $('#fileurl').val(data[0]);
            $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + data[1] + ')');
            $('#bars').val(data[2]);
            $('#bpm').val(data[3]);
        }
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

**generate.php** (it preforms functions before this, but this is the only data I need to return to my jquery and the rest of the page)

```
echo $fileurl,$imageurl,$bars,$randbpm;
```

I am not sure but I think its something with the 'data:' in jQuery, I just need to find out how to return the echo data

When I click the button it is working and creating a new loop its just not returning the echo data properly so I know the path is correct to generate.php

**EDIT: (Solution)**

Thanks @Thamilan for the help! I had to make a few small changes to jquery to update the audio player it is all now working like desired:

**Jquery**

```
<script>
$('#button1').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'generate.php',
    data: $(this).val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        var fileName = data[0];
        $("#music").attr("src",fileName).trigger("play");
        $('#timeline').css('background-image', 'url(' + data[1] + ')');
        $('#bars').text(data[2]);
        $('#bpm').text(data[3]);
    }
}); 
  });
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
$returnArr = [$fileurl,$imageurl,$bars,$randbpm];    
echo json_encode($returnArr);
```

Comment: Is this a form button? Need to prevent the default submit if it is

Comment: Just a div <div id="button1"><div class="namething">Generate</div></div>

Comment: Most likely your path is incorrect to `'generate.php'`

Comment: Add those to an array. Send as a JSON from generate, get JSON in AJAX, print out.

Comment: I just checked my database and when I click the button it is working and creating a new loop its just not returning the echo data properly so I know the path is correct to generate.php

Comment: You should not post your solution into the question. If it is worth it, paste it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `generate.php` add those to an array and encode to JSON and send. Get JSON in AJAX, print out.

Make your AJAX similar to:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'generate.php',
    data: $(this).val(),
    dataType: 'json',          //Added this
    success: function(data){   //value to data
        $('#fileurl').val(data[0]);
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + data[1] + ')');
        $('#bars').val(data[2]);
        $('#bpm').val(data[3]);
    }
});
```

**generate.php**

```
$returnArr = [$fileurl,$imageurl,$bars,$randbpm];    
echo json_encode($returnArr);
```

Comment: Hey Thamilan, This is working now, it is returning the data! Thanks!